# React-router clickable elements inside Link

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I've got a following element inside `<Link>` component:

[image]

It needs to be whole clickable and it needs to preserve cmd/ctrl + click functionality (also right mouse button + open in new tab). The problem is that I need to enable clicking also on `times` icon without transition to a new location. Is it somehow possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `onClick` event on the `times` icon is triggering the parent `onClick` which is the `Link` component which is the default behavior.

To prevent this you should add `e.preventDefault()` in your function:

```
onClick={(e) => e.preventDefault()}
```

Note: It might also be a good idea to use `e.stopPropagation();` alongside `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: Thanks! I've got there only `evt.stopPropagation()` before, now it works with `preventDefault()` :)